# Mongo + RoR Models. Stuck with NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, model, nomethoderror

I have a problem with NoMethodError in one of my models.

In the log file, we have:

```
   NoMethodError (undefined method `length=' for #<Book:0x000000083866b8>):
2013-03-28T10:25:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/engine/book.rb:13:in `block in find_or_create_by_guide'
2013-03-28T10:25:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/engine/book.rb:9:in `find_or_create_by_guide'
```

Let me go through all of the important files.

For a start, we have Mongo's document.rb:

```
   class Guide::Document
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :city, Integer
  key :trips, Array
  key :themes, Array
  key :places, Array
  key :pace, String
  key :date_from, Time
  key :date_to, Time
  key :host, String
  key :length, Integer
  timestamps!
end
```

Then, the book model is called upon the guide document:

```
module ClassMethods
  def find_or_create_by_guide(guide)
    book = ::Book.find_or_create_by_document(guide.id.to_s) do |b|
      b.city_id = guide.city
      b.host    = guide.host
      b.pace    = guide.pace || :normal
      b.length  = guide.length
    end
```

later in the book.rb, I have the following line:

```
groups = sorted_points.in_groups_of(self.length.count, false)
```

`Length.rb`:

```
  class Length < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book

  attr_accessible :book_id
end
```

`Book.rb`:

```
attr_accessible :user_id, :country_id, :city_id, :hotel_id, :type, :price, :host, :pace, :created_at, :updated_at, :length
```

Finally, the migrations of Length:

```
class AddLengthColumnToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :books, :length, :integer
  end
end
```

Any hints or tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mess. Once you want 'length' to be an attribute of Book, once you want Length to be a separate model which is in a relation with Book.
I see no point in having Length model.
Go with 'length' as a Book property.

Comment: I'm totally basic in development so I try to approach this from various angles. Based on what you've written, I'll:
1) Delete length model.
2) Add attr_accessor :length to Book.rb
3) Then delete b.length  = guide.length, and simply call length with self. when I need it (like in groups = sorted_points.in_groups_of(self.length.count, false) )

Comment: 1) yes; 2) no, you added 'legth' column in a migration, so you don't need attr_accessor; 3) b.length = guide.length seems ok, you can't just call self.length, because inside ClassMethods 'self' isn't a Book instance

Comment: Ok, so if I leave b.length = guide.length, then would 'groups = sorted_points.in_groups_of(self.length.count, false)' be a correct way to divide the sorted_points? One last question: is 'count' actually needed with self.length, if the length itself is an integer?

Comment: #in_groups_of is just a method of Array accepting an integer argument, so it should work, but of course you need to get rid of 'count' and just go with: sorted_points.in_groups_of(length, false)

Comment: NP, enjoy Rails as much as I do!